# Migrate from restful_authentication to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i've been using rails 2 for a project and restful_authentication with it. Recently, i changed that project to rails 3 and i found out about devise, that to my eyes seems a much better solution that restful_authentication.

Therefore, i decided that it would be a good idea to migrate to devise, but it seems that the procedure is pretty tedious and error prone. I would like to ask you if you know of any good resource that describes the procedure, because doing it from scratch is a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate
```

That's all there is for now, you get routes and functionality like `/users/sign_(in|out|up)` from start.

Resources:

- [Railscasts "Introducing Devise"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)
- [Devise Readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#readme)
- [Example application](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example)

Comment: that's the installation part :P Migrating from restful_authentication though involves some more things, like messing with the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Migrating from Restful Authentication to Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657145/migrating-from-restful-authentication-to-devise), but so far nothing for me. :(